# Session Management For redirection in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want  to manage page redirection in codeigniter, I have two controllers:

1. Logggedin
2. login

When user try to access `login` page while he is logged in, he is redirected to `Loggedin` controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $u = $this->session->userdata('username');

    if(! isset($u))
    {
        redirect('loggedin');
    }
}
```

And when he tries to access `Loggedin` controller while he is not logged in, he should be redirected to `login` controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $u = $this->session->userdata('username');

    if(isset($u))
    {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

But when I press logout button, it has to redirect to `Login` controller, but he still remains on `Logggedin` controller.

```
function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login');
}
```

What could be the problem in code?

Comment: Can you post all the code for both controllers?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use codeigniter redirect function you must include the codeigniter url helper file, in which this function is actually written.

So, Load the codeigniter url helper  file in your constructor

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

and try by putting a '/' in front of the uri segment

```
redirect('/login');
```

Your redirect function is not working, as on logout, your session is destroyed, but the redirect is not taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is always returning `true`

```
$u=$this->session->userdata('username');

// this is ALWAYS true because $u will equal the value from session or false
if(!isset($u))
{
  redirect('loggedin');
}
```

Instead, you should do this

```
$u=$this->session->userdata('username');
if( ! $u)
{
  redirect('loggedin');
}
```

The `userdata` method will return a `boolean(false)` if the data is not present.

[From the Code Igniter Manual - Retrieving Session Data](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

> Note: The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are trying
>   to access does not exist.

Comment: but then why his logout not working? His code is not redirecting properly.

Comment: I'm sure there are other issues with the code, which will be exposed as an infinite redirect when he gets the conditionals fixed.  If the url helper isn't loaded, he'd be getting a `fatal error`..